# Multiple plot single colorbar in python matplotlib basemap system crash problem

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib-basemap

Why I am getting a runtime error while running this code?? I wanted to show two SST data in a single plot using for loop. while I am running the code it shows your system has crashed. I am sharing the screenshot of the system log.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYuXK.png)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import ImageGrid



def read_sst (x):
    ncfile=x
    fh=Dataset(ncfile,mode='r')
    sst=fh.variables['sst'][:]
    sst_anom=sst[0,:,:]
    return sst_anom


sst_anom_drought=read_sst("Drought_SST_Mean_Anomaly_Composite_1901-2014.nc") 
sst_anom_flood=read_sst("Flood_SST_Mean_Anomaly_Composite_1901-2014.nc")



SST_ncfile='Flood_SST_Mean_Anomaly_Composite_1901-2014.nc'
fh1=Dataset(SST_ncfile,mode='r')
lons = fh1.variables['longitude'][:]  
lats = fh1.variables['latitude'][:] 


sst_data=[sst_anom_drought,sst_anom_flood]

fig = plt.figure(1,(15.,5.))
grid_top = ImageGrid(fig, 111, nrows_ncols = (2, 1),axes_pad=0.5)
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.25,0.15, 0.55, 0.015])

for g, s in zip(grid_top,sst_data):
    plt.sca(g)
    m = Basemap(resolution='l',projection='merc',llcrnrlon=30, llcrnrlat=-31,
    urcrnrlon=360, urcrnrlat=65)
    clevs = np.linspace(-0.8, 0.8, 15)
    lons, lats = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
    xi, yi = m(lons, lats)
    color_map = plt.cm.RdBu_r
    #reversed_color_map = color_map.reversed()
    cs = m.contourf(xi,yi,s,clevs,cmap=color_map,extend='both')
    cb=fig.colorbar(cs,orientation="horizontal",cax=cbar_ax) 
    m.drawparallels(np.arange(-30., 65., 15.), labels=[1,0,0,0], fontsize=12,linewidth=0.1)
    m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 180., 40.), labels=[0,0,0,1], fontsize=12,linewidth=0.1)
    m.fillcontinents(color='whitesmoke',lake_color='whitesmoke')
    m.drawcoastlines()
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to allocate too much memory with the plot commands.